# String split in java does not work?

Tags: java, split, emoticons

I split this String by space : `String input = ":-) :) :o) :] :3 :c) :> =] 8) =) :} :^)";` (space between emoticons)

And result is:

```
:-)?:)?:o)?:]?:3?:c)?:>
=]

8)

=)?:}?:^)
```

There are  some strange characters in the results. I don't know why. Please help me.

Here is the code:

```
fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("emoticon.txt"));
String line = "";
while ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null){
    String[] icons = parts[0].split("\\s+");
    ....
}
```

Thank for any advices.
Here is emoticon file: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ovz0aupqo1utrx/emoticon.txt

Comment: Please show the code you used.

Comment: I just use input.split(" "); // very simple one.

Comment: When I split these icon by typing it in the code -> it works
But when I read these String from file -> it does not works.Here is file https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ovz0aupqo1utrx/emoticon.txt

Comment: @HoaVu i updated my ans. Check code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String input = ":-) :) :o) :] :3 :c) :> =] 8) =) :} :^)";
String[] similies = input.split(" ");
for (String simili : similies) {
    System.out.println(simili);
}
```

This works fine.
Output :

```
:-)
:)
:o)
:]
:3
:c)
:>
=]
8)
=)
:}
:^)
```

and in case if there is any tab/newline/spaces and you wnat to split, in that case you can use

```
input.split("\\s+");
```

in your example there is few more charaters are their like Â and non breaking whitespaces so you have to explicitly handle these type of charater. Here is the code:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("emoticon.txt"));
    String line = "";
    while ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
        line = line.replaceAll("Â", "");
        line = line.replace("" + ((char) 160), " ");
            System.out.println("line: " + line);
        String[] icons = line.split("\\s+");
        for (String icon : icons) {
            System.out.println(icon);
        }
        System.out.println("=======================");
    }
}
```

Comment: It not works for me. May be the file in my computer has problem. How could upload it here, please ?

Comment: Just copy and paste your code as it is in your question where yor are trying to split this ans there is no option to upload any file on SO.You can either upload on google doc and share path on SO.

Answer (score 2):

They may not be just space characters; they could be tabs etc.

Instead, try splitting on *whitespace* characters (regex `\s`), rather than just specifically *space* characters:

```
String[] emoticons = input.split("\\s+");
```

---

I analysed the file referred to in the comment and found that some of the "spaces" were actually characters with decimal value `160` (hex `A0`). By changing the split regex to include this character, I was able to split every emoticon:

```
String[] emoticons = input.split("[\\s\u00A0]+");
```

Comment: I think may be the file I used has problem. How can I upload it here, please?

Comment: This really should work. did you copy-paste my code when you tried it? Did you paste your exact input into the question - if not just paste it in and format it as "code"

Comment: When I split these icon by typing it into the code -> it works But when I read these String from file -> it does not works.Here is file dropbox.com/s/6ovz0aupqo1utrx/emoticon.txt

Answer (score 1):

Since you are seeing newlines in your output, it could mean that the original string that you have as input may consist of whitespace as newline, tabs, etc. apart from space.

So, you need to split the string on whitespace:

```
String[] spiltted = input.split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a regular expression.

[split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Try with

```
String[] array = input.split("\\s+");
```

Comment: Fyi That will split on every character

Comment: @nachokk I tried to run your code in terminal and the result:
:-)?:)?:o)?:]?:3?:c)?:>

=]

8)
=)?:}?:^)